# Can I have a Partial controller in Zend?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

In the Zend Framework is it possible to have a controller which executes some logic and then sets some view variables ready for the partial to display?

---

To clarify I have a view which implements a partial.

I have logic in my partial to get some items from the database. It then displays the items.

At the moment the logic is in the partial's view (.pthml file).

Is there a controller or something I can use to execute this logic outside the partial view?

As I understand the MVP pattern, I shouldn't have logic like this in the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping logic out of your view is a good thing and that is what [view helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html) are designed for.

The section on [writing your own](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.custom) will be of particular interest to you.

This will allow you to keep logic out of the view by writing something like:-

```
<?php echo $this->getItems(); ?>
```

in your view rather than having the logic there.

Creating a helper called getItems for example is quite easy. Create `application/views/helpers/GetItems.php` and create your helper:-

```
class Zend_View_Helper_GetItems extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function getItems()
    {
        //Do some stuff
        return $this->view->escape("Did some stuff!");
    }
}
```

Then call it as above, you don't have to do anything else.

Comment: Huge thanks! I tried this originally when you answered but I just realised I had a error in my code which is why it wasn't working.